# Confused what I should be playing

Tags: bass-guitar

what notes does a bass player play in relation to the Rhythm guitarist?

Comment: Hello, please be more specific. Take some time to ask a well phrased and understandable question, as you’d expect us to take time to answer it.

Comment: Perhaps your question is about the best way to interpret lead sheet chord symbol notation, or maybe it’s about rules of thumb for how to start going beyond that. I’m voting to close this question as “needs details or clarity“; I can retract my vote if it’s edited to become clear.

Comment: Please also clarify the genre. 5-piece pop-rock band, metal, and jazz band might all get different answers.

Comment: [edit] the question, **not in comments**, adding all the context you can so we can understand you. Are you in a band? You have to compose the bass for original songs? How long have you been playing bass? Etc.

Comment: I hate to vote to close a question about bass but there is just not enough info in the question to respond with anything but an entire method book. @ScottFogarty please add more info, include your ability level, musical style and anything else you think might help get a more specific answer.

Comment: With your back to them and facing the drummer it doesn't matter what they're doing. They're the one who should be asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

Find some recordings that are stylistically similar to the music you want to play and listen to what the bass is playing. Try to emulate it. Once you've learned your role in the band you can add your own ideas.
If you are playing from chord sheets the root of the chord is never a bad choice to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The rhythm guitarist will be playing chords. or perhaps in some situations, like big bands, jazz ensembles, partial chords. Those chords are what are prescribed over each bar, and will comprise ^1, ^3, ^5, sometimes ^7. With extended and altered chords, ^5 will be left out, and even ^1 may not be played.

The simplest bass will put down a root of those chords, generally on beat 1 (1 on 1), and supplement that with a ^5 on beat 3 (in 4/4 time!). That can be augmented with a ^3 as well, outlining the triad that the guitarist would play, in single notes.

There are other occasions where the bass line will pre-empt a change of chord, climbing up the scale, for example, on a C7 chord, leading to an F, notes C,C,D,E, in that bar. Or C,B♭,A,G, to reach said F note on the 1st beat of the F bar.

On yet other occasions, a *walking bass* will be employed, where the bassline literally walks up and down the scale, with appropriate key notes played on important beats.

There are many other ideas, but with nothing much else to go on, I hope that goes some way to an appropriate answer!

Comment: The OP's question suggests a level of confusion that wouldn't even be clear on what "root of chord" means. Or maybe not. That's why I vtc'd as unclear rather than hazard an answer.